# Wipe Laptop Hard Disk on boot

Tags: windows-7, boot, windows-8-preview

I've got a MacBook pro.  It's got Win7 installed (from scratch...I blew away stupid Mac OS).

Now I'm installing Win 8 preview, got the boot disk (iso).  I run it but Windows 8 says that windows (existing Win7) needs to be repaired.

So I just want to wipe the hard drive completely.  Not really a low-level 1s and 0s, but just delete partitions.  I do not have the win 7 CD with me.  So is there a FREE quality bootable program that will allow me to see the current hard drive and erase everything on it?  I could write the bootable program to USB or CD, boot, erase, then reboot using the Win 8 preview iso and all will be fine.  Just gotta get there and first erase this disk.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ultimate Boot CD to boot and completly erase your hard drive:

[Ultimate Boot CD v5.1.1 download page](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/download.html)

[P2P torrent file for Ultimate Boot CD v5.1.1](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/download/ubcd511.iso.torrent)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a 3rd party disk, just use the windows disk itself (or whatever you are using to install windows 8)

Run the following command (assuming drive C here):

`format C: /FS:NTFS /Q /X`